# How to optimise SQL a/avg(a)?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my SQL script, I want to standardize a value which comes from a subquery like this

```
select y/avg(y) from (
   select x*z as y from test_table
)T
```

I know this solution will work

```
select y/avg_y from (
       select id, x*z as y from test_table
    )T
join(
  select avg(y) as avg_y
  from(
    select x*z as y from test_table
  )a
)T2
```

But I donot want to caculate y twice, is there good idea?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL, are there any difference with databse?

Comment: Yes, there are differences between all databases, MySQL for instance does not support analytic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ANSI standard mechanism is:

```
select y / (avg(y) over ())
from (select x*z as y from test_table) T
```

or:

```
select x * z / (avg(x * z) over ())
from test_table;
```

This uses window functions, which are supported by most databases.

EDIT:

MySQL does not support window functions.  If you don't want to do the calculation twice, you can use a trick with variables:

```
select y / (@sy / @rn)
from (select x*z as y,
             @rn := if(x*z is not null, @rn + 1, @rn),
             @s := if(x*z is not null, @s + x*z, @s)
      from test_table t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @sy := 0) params
     ) t;
```

The variables should be created for the subquery before they are used in the outer query.

And, a simpler way to write the query without variables doesn't use as many subqueries:

```
select (t.x * t.z)/ a.avg_y
from test_table t cross join
     (select avg(x*z) as avg_y
      from test_table
     ) a;
```